# Is it safe to call ConnectivityManager's requestNetwork() on Main thread?

Tags: android

Is it safe to call requestNetwork() Interface of ConnectivityManager via Main thread or it pauses threat of ANR error ?

Comment: Yes it is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is an async operation. You'll receive updates via `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback` callback.

Don't forget to unregister with `unregisterNetworkCallback` when updates are no longer needed to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer doing every task related to networking in a separate background thread... As it does not block the ui... But Since ul b using a Broadcast Receiver... It is synchronous by default.. So u dont have to for reciever..

Comment: agreed, However in this case we provide the callback to ConnectivityManager whenever available or unavailable etc. so Does it still block the UI ?

Comment: As a callback... Ul be using broadcast receiver which is synchronous... So it wont block the ui though